# MTOM Request / Non-MTOM Response

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, mtom

We have a pretty simple WS, implemented using annotations. We would like to be able to call this from clients both supporting MTOM/XOP and not. 
Right now, it is annotated simply @MTOM.

It takes a request containing (amongst others) a base64Binary element, and serves a response containing a single boolean element.

Calling it is no problem, either with our without MTOM - it works. Only, the response, even though it doesn't contain any MTOM:able elements has headers declaring it a MTOM message, which chokes the non-MTOM client.

```
<tran:headers   xsi:type="http:HttpResponseHeaders" xmlns:http="http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/transports/http"  xmlns:tran="http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/transports"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <tran:user-header   name="X-Powered-By" value="Servlet/2.5 JSP/2.1"/>
 <http:Content-Type>
  multipart/related;start="&lt;rootpart*c3e56707-113c-47f9-b02c-2a3234766dc4@example.jaxws.sun.com>";type="application/xop+xml";boundary="uuid:c3e56707-113c-47f9-b02c-2a3234766dc4";start-info="text/xml"
 </http:Content-Type>
 <http:Date>Tue, 11 May 2010 07:27:51 GMT</http:Date>
 <http:Transfer-Encoding>chunked</http:Transfer-Encoding>
</tran:headers>
```

Does anyone know how to get the service to always respond with a non-MTOM response while still accepting both MTOM and non-MTOM requests?

The service runs on a WebLogic 10.3 server...

Kind regards,
Lars

Comment: got any answer about this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Actually what I found odd was if I don't put an `@MTOM` the resulting message never returns a mutli-part message.  However, the web service still accepts the MTOM data in WebSphere.